# Why redux mapStateToProps doesn't update component props even if store is updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Redux store is updating correctly but react components props are not. I checked redux global state with a remote dev tool and it's updating as expected. 
 
But when i check component props with react-devtools it isn't updating. 
If i call getUserPublis() in a higher order component (index e.g) then mapStateToProps maps these props correctly, but when i create a new item it's not mapped (but its correctly updated into the store). 
It's like if  **mapStateToProps() is not being called when redux state update**

```
class Profile extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation, screenProps}) => ({
        title: 'Perfil',
        headerRight: <HeaderButton navigation={navigation}/>,
    });

    componentDidMount(){
        getUserPublis(this.props.userData.ownPublis)
    }
    onPressCard = (publi) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('cardDescription', {
            data: publi,
            user: props.userName
        })
    }

    maybeRenderAddButton = () => {
        if (this.props.userData.isCommerce){
            return(
                <FloatingButton
                    icon="md-add"
                    color="white"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('offerNew', {
                        title: "Crear anuncio"
                    })}
                />
            )
        } else {
            return console.log('no hay add button')
        }
    }

    render(){
        this.maybeRenderAddButton()
        if (this.props.publis.length === 0) {
            return(
                <Text> Loading </Text>
            )   
        }
        return (
            <ScrollView>
            {
                this.props.publis.map((publi, index) => {
                        return(
                            <CardGeneral
                                key={index}
                                onPressCard={() => onPressCard(publi)}
                                data={publi}
                                user={this.props.user.displayName}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                )
            }

            </ScrollView>


            );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        user: state.auth.user,
        userData: state.firestore.userData,
        publis: state.publis
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile)
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = []

function publis(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FIRESTORE_PUBLI_SNAPSHOT': {
            return [
                ...state,
                action.payload.data
            ]
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default publis
```

Comment: Try to add a simple `console.log` into mapStateToProps function to see whether it's called when state.publis changes. If it's not, something is wrong with redux implementation (maybe missing a Provided or reducer not included in rootStore).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i have the answer, it's unbelievable because i expended almost 5 days with this bug and as you can see there is nothing visibly wrong in the code. 
For this app my stack is: react-native, **expo**, react-navigation and redux. 
The problem, is apparently with expo because when i use simulator to run the app in development mode, the issue is there (mapStateToProps is called just once when the component is mounted),  **but when i ran the app in android device everything goes fine**, but just for the first time that i ran... The next time the app has the same issue in android device and ios simulator. So i tried to run the app in 'expo development mode', and magically everything goes fine. 
This is a problem because developer mode is slow and i can't use developer tools, but is good to know what is the real problem. Now i'm gonna post this in expo forum. 
PD: I already updated expo and clear expo cache.

Comment: The bug has been solved on expo v32, if you are facing this bug you should start updating expo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake with expo + react-navigation + redux + firebase, spent a week searching for a solution. Redux State was updated correctly, it was visible on Dev Tools, but there was no change in the component props. Properties were updated only when the component was first rendered.

In my case, the problem was solved by switching mode of the Expo to production mode.

[image: Here is the switch image in Expo v32]

Answer (score 0):

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getUserPublis})(Profile)
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?

Comment: all actions which are calling by your component you should also connect with your react component in curly brackets, or define them  in mapDispatchToProps which is analog of  mapStateToProps.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it should work

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(Profile)
```